# How to get Voronoi area of a GeoDataFrame? Aka: how to relate the result polygons with initial points?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, voronoi

I want to assign the Voronoi area to the originating points.
I got inspiration from shapely documentation: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#voronoi-diagram .
But as we see from the example, the first point is `(0,0)`, but the first polygon has the vertex `(2,1)` (it describes the polygon in the center). But so now I lost the relation between points and polygons.

Is there a better way to relate the polygon (so the area) to the initial point?

My full code:

```
# gdf = is a GeoDataFrame
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = gdf.total_bounds
bound = Polygon([(minx, miny),
                    (maxx, miny),
                    (maxx, maxy),
                    (minx, maxy)])
points = MultiPoint(gdf.geometry.to_list())
parcels = voronoi_diagram(points , envelope=bound)
areas = [p.area for p in parcels]
gdf['area'] = areas
```

The relation can be calculated (only one point is contained in a polygon), but I have a lot of data (millions of points), so I'm looking for a better solution. As you see there may be unnecessary conversion from geopandas into point and back.

Comment: Why are you using shapely's dummy data with geopandas? These are no geolocations. You could use [geovoronoi](https://github.com/WZBSocialScienceCenter/geovoronoi) in combination with geopandas.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen: Thank you, that seems interesting. Note: it never show up to me in my googling. I thin it would good if you add an answer (with example). (I would iterate with `region_polys`)

Answer (score -1):

Using the `geovoronoi` library, the function `voronoi_regions_from_coords` does what you want I believe.